# Databases: How to store a date unknown vs date that hasn't occurred yet

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL with a field of type `DATE` for storing some dates, and I have another table in which I have a field of type `SMALLINT` for storing only a year.

Now I need to differentiate between a date (or a year) that is simply unknown from a date (or a year) that hasn't occurred yet. It's pretty straightforward that unknown values should be `NULL`. But is there any recommendation as to what value to use to store dates that haven't yet occurred with the types I mentioned?

I'm quite sure that no dates / years before 1000 will ever be used, so I could use e.g. `0000-01-01`. Is there any better / recommended solution?

**EDIT** Just read that for the `DATE` type "The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'." So I would have to use `1000-01-01` instead of `0000-01-01`.

Comment: Why not just use the future date?  Like 2020-05-02 or whatever?  Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @Corbin Yes, it is a possibility; I could use e.g. `9999-12-31`, but as unlikely as it is for my db to ever need to store any data in a few thousand years, it seems cleaner to use a date that has absolutely 0 chance of ever being needed. I'm just curious if there is any recommended way to handle my problem.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using null for both situations then.  What exactly are these dates?  Your requirement isn't make much sense.   "it seems cleaner...0 chance..."  What do you mean?  You should use either null, or the actual date?

Comment: I need to differentiate unknowns from the dates that haven't occurred. Imagine a "Date died" field in some kind of a db storing famous ppl files. If a person hasn't died yet, then the value can't be marked as unknown; it just hasn't occured. However, if the person has died, the editors need to know that the info requires completion.

Comment: @Corbin It just occurred to me, you're right. Obviously, it is actually logical and better to use a date in the far future. Forget my previous comment. Actually, I would accept your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to use one column to store two separate bits of data. Whether someone is dead or alive (effectively a status field) and the date on which they died are separate bits of info. As such, I'd suggest you store them separately. Whether someone is alive or dead without the date of their death being known, the date of death is NULL in either case. I wouldn't use the date field to determine whether or not they are dead. Thus I would suggest a TINYINT (or BOOL) column to store whether they are alive or not and a NULL-able DATE field for their date of death.

Comment: Initially I was reluctant to try this thinking it might be a terrible waste of space to store a bool in an additional field; however, quick calculations show that even with millions of records the additional space needed is negligible. I had to think on it for a while, considering what queries etc. I might need in the future, and finally I came to conclusion that this solution is the best for my case. Thanks!